# Get response information from useFetch in Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, fetch-api, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I would like to wrap the whole response returned by `useFetch` & `$fetch` in a custom `ApiResponse` class.
This class has methods to access the response data as well as the status, headers etc.
However, `useFetch` only returns the data, so I came up with this:

```js
// a wrapper method in my api service class
useFetch(options = {}, url: string = this.url) {
    let responseMeta

    return useFetch(url, {
        onResponse: ({ response }) => {
            responseMeta = {
                status: response.status,
                headers: response.headers,
                body: response.body,
            }
        },
        transform: (input: any) => new ApiResponse(input, responseMeta),
        ...options,
    })
}
```

However, I'm not sure whether `onResponse` is guaranteed to be called before the `transform` callback. The same goes for a `$fetch` wrapper:

```js
async fetch(options = {}, url: string = this.url) {
    let responseMeta

    const data = await $fetch(url, {
        onResponse: ({ response }) => {
            responseMeta = {
                status: response.status,
                headers: response.headers,
                body: response.body,
            }
        },
        ...options,
    })
    return new ApiResponse(data, responseMeta)
}
```

Can this be improved in any way? I'm not sure I like this solution very much...
Thanks!

*PS: I have setup custom serializers for the classes so that's not an issue*

---

**EDIT:** After looking at the `ofetch` source code, I found out that `onResponse` looks to be indeed called before `$fetch` resolves.

```js
// inside $fetchRaw
if (context.options.onResponse) {
    await context.options.onResponse(context as any);
}


// the actual $fetch
const $fetch = async function $fetch(request, options) {
    const r = await $fetchRaw(request, options);
    return r._data;
  } as $Fetch;
```